# Convert a float column with nan to int pandas

Tags: pandas, transform, apply, data-transform

I am trying to convert a float pandas column with `nans` to int format, using apply.
I would like to use something like this:

```
df.col = df.col.apply(to_integer)
```

where the function `to_integer` is given by

```
def to_integer(x):
    if np.isnan(x):
        return np.NaN
    else:
        return int(x)
```

However, when I attempt to apply it, the column remains the same.

How could I achieve this without having to use the standard technique of dtypes?

Comment: You can't have NaN in an `int` column. NaNs are `floats`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `NaN` in an `int` column, `NaN` are `float` (unless you use an `object` type, which is not a good idea since you'll lose many vectorial abilities).

You can however use the new [nullable integer type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) (`NA`).

Conversion can be done with [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 2, None]})
df = df.convert_dtypes()

# type(df.at[0, 'col'])
# numpy.int64

# type(df.at[2, 'col'])
# pandas._libs.missing.NAType
```

output:

```
    col
0     1
1     2
2  <NA>
```

Comment: Can you show to OP the output of `type(df.loc[0, 'col'])` to be sure 1 is now an integer (`np.int64`)?

Comment: @Corralien sure! NB. you can also edit my posts if you want in such cases ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would achieve this without using dtypes. Sometimes when loading in data, you may have a column that contains mixed dtypes. Loading in a column with one dtype and attemping to turn it into mixed dtypes is not possible though (at least, not that I know of).

So I will echo what @mozway said and suggest you use [nullable integer data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

e.g

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('Int64')
```

(note the capital `I`)